# Current page doesn't work in wp_login_form

Tags: wordpress, redirect, authentication

I'm using the `wp_login_form()` in my header so that people can log in to my site.

When they click a user icon in the header area, a modal is opened where they can input their username and password and press login.

When they log in, they get redirected to my start page, even though the default value regarding redirect (current page) is inserted. I want them to stay on the current page where they clicked the user icon in the header after they've logged in. Is it possible?

See the code below. I guess I need to change the string after `redirect`. Is there any alternative ways of getting the current page than the usual one?

```
$args = array(
    'echo'           => true,
    'remember'       => true,
    'redirect'       => ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
    'form_id'        => 'loginform',
    'id_username'    => 'user_login',
    'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
    'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
    'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
    'label_username' => __( 'Username or Email Address' ),
    'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
    'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
    'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log In' ),
    'value_username' => '',
    'value_remember' => false
);
```

Comment: where you used `$args`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How do you mean? Sorry, I'm a newbie. The code above is from the general template PHP file in Wordpress (includes).

Answer (score 1):

For this use the login_redirect filter.In this filter one parameter is $request, which is the URL the user is coming from

```
function redirect_to_request( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){

    return $request; // this is the URL the user is coming from
}
add_filter('login_redirect', redirect_to_request, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks! Should this be inserted into functions.php in my theme folder?

Comment: Yes add in function file of your current theme.

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't work. It is still redirecting to the start page after succesful login. I guess the current code can't identify the current page. The login is done through a modal in the header.php - maybe that is the problem? So is there any way of identify the current page instead of the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?

Comment: I have tested this code and its working fine , so I feel there must be some other plugin which conflict it so try to deactivate one by one.